# Split container constrained content with full width split colors/image

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

With bootstrap 4 (or 5) I'm trying to do a split content with it's own unique background colors/images. Effectively I'm looking to use container within a container-fluid. I've looked at options for setting split background colors (like green/orange) using linear-gradient but the problem is that when switching to mobile it tries to split each section of content.

For the image (example image top section purple) I tried to use the solution below but again ran into issues on mobile view. Is there a better way to support these use cases or is the best option to do some mobile specific breakpoints to hide colors/images and then do specific low view port display options?
[Bootstrap - split background container full-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821332/bootstrap-split-background-container-full-width)

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRyk8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you referenced, [Bootstrap - split background container full-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821332/bootstrap-split-background-container-full-width/#answer-64706425), seems to work pretty good (see the code example below). What were the issues you were having on mobile devices?

```css
.bg-fill {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-md">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<section class="position-relative">
    <div class="container-fluid bg-fill">
        <div class="row h-100 text-secondary">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #23A500;">
                <p class="text-start">Left</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #f2a500;">
                <p class="text-end">Right</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-md">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #23A500;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #f2a500;">
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="position-relative">
    <div class="container-fluid bg-fill">
        <div class="row h-100 text-secondary">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #23A500;">
                <p class="text-start">Left</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #f2a500;">
                <p class="text-end">Right</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-md">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #23A500;">
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: #f2a500">
                <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, I must have been missing something somewhere in the example because when I was switching to the mobile viewports it wasn't scaling correctly but the sample you had worked great.